# Trying to generate app bundle but gradle build is running forever

Tags: android, gradle, android-app-bundle

trying to generate an app bundle (new publishing format android suggested). but gradle is running forever.Generating .apk work fine. but not able to generate the app bundle. currently working on android studio 3.5.

tried to do the build process by enabling work offline. still no use.

Gradle build running keep showing.

Comment: What configuration you have of your laptop?

Comment: What task is taking long to run?

Comment: @admin    i am using mac with  processor 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 with memory of 16gb

Comment: @pierre  Not sure which task is taking that much time. didn't  find anything in log. only pop up with gradle build running.